# Process substitution in BSD hangs (sometimes)

Tags: bash, freebsd, process-substitution

While porting a Linux bash script to BSD, I've stumbled on an interesting question.

How can this phenomenon be explained and what workaround would you suggest in this case:

it is a minimal reproducible example, that's why it makes no sense per se)

```
# this works in Linux, but hangs in BSD:
$(a=<(echo 1))
```

It is so called process substitution (inside a command substitution) here, and it works like this:

- Name of a file descriptor (linux), or temporary FIFO file (BSD) is stored in the `$a` variable;
- after that the subshell of the command substitution `$()` is closed.

Ok. That is how it should work (and it works in Linux), but it hangs in FreeBSD, waiting for something to happen with the FIFO created for the command substitution (`/tmp//sh-np.muuX1P`).

Question:

How you can explain this, and what workaround would you propose?

Comment: Please post bash versions on both systems. Please make sure you are really running bash and not other shell.

Comment: @KamilCuk Sure I do. FreeBSD: `5.0.18(3)-release`; Linux: various, all work correctly, current one: `4.4.20(1)-release`

Comment: Note that support for FreeBSD 5.0-RELEASE ended almost 13 years ago and is more than obsolete. We are now on version 12.2 with 13.0 in sight.

Comment: @Rob: Thank you for the info. Please note that it is FreeBSD 12 what I have; it is bash that has `5.0.10(3)-release` (because KamiCuk asked about the bash version)

Comment: The `bash` port is maintained by `ehaupt@FreeBSD.org`, you might want to drop him an email or open a bug report at https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/

Comment: @arrowd: Thank you for suggestion. I've just done it, I've dropped an email to Emanuel; let's see if he answers or not